# Использование PL/SQL переменных в SQL запросах с одноимёнными полями

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Если я объявляю функции и процедуры в пакетах, как я могу использовать объявленные в них PL/SQL переменные в SQL запросах с одноимёнными полями таблиц?

Как обычно с bind переменной `:variable` не работает, т.к. это будет переменная объявленная в вызывающей запрос программе, а не переменная в PL/SQL блоке.

Например анонимный блок:

```
DECLARE

    FUNCTION Dummy RETURN CHAR IS
        Dummy CHAR(1) := 'Y';
        Ret   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT CASE WHEN Dummy = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Ret
        INTO Ret
        FROM DUAL;

        RETURN Ret;
   END Dummy;    

BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dummy='||Dummy);
END;
```

Вернёт `0` потому, что колонка `DUMMY` существует и имеет значение "X", но я то ожидаю `1`.

Можно, например, переименовать переменню во избежание конфликта. А как сделать это лучше?

Comment: Просто не называйте переменные так же как столбцы в используемых таблицах. Никогда.

Comment: @Mike А как их называть? В клиентской части кода переменные называются также как и таблцах поля.

Comment: тогда я не понял суть вопроса. что такое "клиентская часть"

Comment: Если вы все таки о одноименных переменных pl/sql кода и именах колонок, то лично я называю pl/sql переменные со знаком подчеркивания в начале, если они рискуют пересечься с именами в таблицах

Comment: Том советует (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6729304326802) называть локальные переменные на `l_`. А способа указать в запросе, что это именно переменная, а не столбец просто не существует

Comment: @Mike Я наверное не точно сформулировал вопрос. Речь идёт о серверной части кода и о одноимённых полях и переменных. В клиенте я бы сделал так :dummy. Можно конечно по другому назвать переменную, но кодовая конвенция не рекомендует исползовать другие имена, чем в моделе данных. А идея с подчеркиванием вроде не плохая. Это не сильно меняет имя.

Comment: @Mike "переменные со знаком подчеркивания в начале" - наверное в конце, в начале нельзя. Я так часто пишу - `rowid_`

Comment: @0xdb Да, точно :)

Comment: А можно ли без метки это сделать, просто обратиться к переменной функции? Что - то наподобие: set serveroutput on; declare function Dummy RETURN number is Dummy CHAR(1) := 'Y'; Ret number; begin select case when Dummy.dummy = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end as Ret into Ret from dual ; return Ret; end Dummy; begin dbms_output.put_line ('Dummy='||Dummy().Dummy); end my;

Comment: @XXX `Dummy().Dummy` - нет, так нельзя, если я вас правильно понял.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно полъзоваться "пространством имён". В пакетах, функциях и процедурах это их собственные имена. Так же можно определить новое "пространство имён" меткой блока.

Например блок из вопроса будет выглядеть так:

```
<<my>> declare
    function Dummy RETURN number is
        Dummy CHAR(1) := 'Y';
        Ret   number;
    begin
        select case when my.Dummy.dummy = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end as Ret 
        into Ret
        from dual 
        ;
        return Ret;
   end Dummy;     
begin
     dbms_output.put_line ('Dummy='||my.Dummy());
end my;
/    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Dummy=1
```

Конструкция `my.Dummy.dummy` переводится:

```
"мой блок"."функция пустышка"."переменная пустышка".
```

Если ей дать имена со смыслом, то будет вполне читабельный код.

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/nameresolution.htm#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09).

PS *namespace* у Oracle это не тоже самое, что например в C++. Смотри
 *Dot Notation*.

Comment: Да, так работает.